# Original vi (version 1.1): Copy lines to alternate file without using named buffer

Tags: original-vi

To copy a line to the alternate file in original vi I use something like

```
"ayy
:e#
"aP
```

The first vi version did have the alternate file feature (with switch command `` :e` ``) but did not have named buffers. Is there a *reasonable* way to copy lines between two files in original vi *without* using named buffers?

Comment: "To copy a line to the alternate file in original vi I use something like" did you mean "in vim"?

Comment: No, in vim copying between buffers works as simple as copying in just one file. In original vi you can't just use `Y` to copy between files since the copy buffer is cleared when switching to the alternate file.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but could you not just add a mapping for this?

Comment: Macros (`:map`) had been introduced in version 3.1. My question is regarding version 1.1. (Not related: I thought that something like `:3,2w temp`, `` :e` ``, `:r temp` could do the job, but this sets the alternate filename to temp, which is undesired...)

Comment: You can use `:r!/bin/cat file` instead of `:read` to avoid setting the alternate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I used to use a real `vi`, I'd write to and read from a file,
like you mention in your comment. I had something like this in my `.exrc`:

```
ab wtemp w !/bin/cat > ~/temp
ab rtemp r !/bin/cat ~/temp
```

So to yank the current line:

```
:.wtemp
```

Or set marks, then:

```
:'a,'b wtemp
```

Then hit `^6` to switch to the alternate file (same as `:e #`), then:

```
:rtemp
```

You can change the abbreviations to mappings if that's easier.

Note that using `:read !` and `:write !` with `cat` avoids setting the alternate file.

As an aside, should you ever use Vim, you can remove the `a` flag
from `'cpoptions'` to prevent `:read` with a filename from setting
the alternate file, and similarly with `A` for writing.

**EDIT**

Looking at the reference manual for v1.1, the command set appears to be highly restrictive.
The only way I can see to achieve the copy in this early version of vi is to append to the alternate file:

```
:[range] write! >> `
```

Then switch to the alternate file and move the appended lines to where you want.

Comment: I gave a +1 for the very useful information on later vi versions (especially `^6`), but unfortunately it doesn't work with with ex-1.1 (https://github.com/n-t-roff/ex-1.1). This version did not have `:ap`, and `w ! /bin/cat > ~/temp` gives the error "Multiple file names allowed only on next command".

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That is indeed a highly restricted command set. Maybe it's time for an upgrade! :-) See the edit for a possible workaround; I can't test it myself however. I'm assuming ` is expanded to the alternate filename for `:write` like for `:!` -- the manual isn't clear.

Comment: It does unfortunately remove all other lines from the alternate file. Nethertheless I accepted the answer. I has very useful information and in the original question I forgot to restrict the problem to vi version 1.

Comment: Thanks! That's unfortunate: the manual claims it should append. Oh well!

Comment: It does. It was a porting bug--the lseek(2) return value differs from seek(2).